# 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 overheating

Tags: cooling-system, dodge, ram

I have a 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 two wheel drive with a 4.7 liter engine.

It's been overheating so I replaced the whole cooling system:

- I replaced the condenser cooling fan because its not coming on when the trucks getting hot. It comes on when I turn the AC on.
- I replaced the relays, also still not working
- I am getting no fault codes, no check engine light

The only other thing I think it could be is the computer.

Comment: Could you add more specific information on what was replaced in the cooling system. The AC fan has nothing to do if the truck is overheating.

Comment: Did you replace water pump, do a hot flush, did you replace the radiator cap? Is the system full of coolant? Is the coolant 50/50 or all antifreeze?

Comment: I'm going to ask the stupid question here: **Did you change the thermostat?**

Comment: Here are the things that I replaced I replace the water pump the thermostat the coolant temperature sensor the belt the fan clutch. I checked all fuses and I replaced the relay switch for the condenser fan and by the way it does help cool your car because when your car starts getting hot that fan comes on to help cool it and also comes on when you turn the AC on

Comment: That is the problem that fan isn't coming on when the vehicle gets hot it only is coming on when you use the AC

Comment: Does your Ram have two electric fans?

Comment: And it's attached to the condenser radiator not the main radiator and it's supposed to come on when the car starts getting a little hot and it's not

Comment: Can you check the condition of your fan wiring? If the wires are brittle then they could be the reason for an open circuit.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that was the intended logic of that fan.  The fan turns on when you turn on the AC, so that verifies the wiring, fuse, and relay are good.  Does it overheat stopped at idle, moving down the road, both?

Comment: It gets hot weather I am sitting or moving

Comment: I think that it is whatever tells that fan to come on when the vehicle starts heating up because it used to come on you know every so often when the vehicle without a certain temperature in and never got hot but now that fan isn't coming on so if it's the computer that tells it to come on I think there's something wrong with the computer

Answer (score 2):

I believe that fan has a two speed motor, three leads on it.  One is low speed operation which is turned on by the AC system.  The second is the warm engine connection which is high speed fan.  This is controlled via a temperature switch through a relay.
With this knowledge need to test and or replaced the temperature sensor and the relay that is this high speed part of the fan.  Or if you have a volt meter then measure the fan connection for this high speed circuit looking for it to turn on and off with rising heat.
The circuit is pretty much the temp sensor, relay, fuse, and fan (plus wiring).

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer exactly but I can't comment yet...sorry for that...

It might sound weird but sometimes wrong cam timing can cause overheating of a motor because the combustion is not as efficient as it should. A lot of the heat is trapped inside the chamber and not exiting the cylinder properly. Since you replace the whole cooling system that is the most logical explanation.

Finally make sure that nothing is blocking the airflow to the radiator. The most obvious is in front of the bumper but don't forget the section between the bumper and the radiator.

Comment: I think wrong cam timing (on non-adjustable cams) would create a lot more symptoms than overheating.  Still, this fully qualifies as an answer, not a comment.  Thanks for you participation.

Answer (score 0):

Try burping the system. My 02 dodge did same thing and I replaced water pump,  thermostat, fan clutch, radiator, and even flush the system. Some reason heater core sits higher than reservoir so you have to Jack front end up on ramps and then burp the system. Once I did this no more running hot.

Answer (score 0):

When the vehicle is cold pull the radiator cap off making sure that the radiator is full of antifreeze start the vehicle up now if you see bubbles coming up from the antifreeze almost at a regular pace it may be a blown head gasket